# Add iterations to loop AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi something simple is annoying me and I'd like some help!

```
    function highlight(textField:TextField):void
    {
        var l:int = textField.text.length

            for(var i:int = 0; i < l; i++)
                if (!highlightChar(textField, i))
                    l++;

    }
```

This loops through a character string to add a box behind the character for a highlighter affect. Some of the characters fail (the bounding box is null, assume these are returns etc) and in the example I'm looking at it returns false 5 times, and the boxes are 5 characters short.  I'm attempting to add another iteration when it fails to keep going for another 5 characters, but this loop never stops.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Is your end goal to "add another iteration when it fails..." or is that what you've done here in this code? The reason why you have an infinite loop is because you're successfully adding iterations, and you never stop adding iterations.

Comment: Yes. That's the goal. To add a few more when it fails. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: You're successfully adding more when it fails by doing `l++`. However, this is giving you an infinite loop because `i` needs to be greater than `l` before the loop will end.

Comment: Hmm OK so the failures are being counted in the new loops - I need to stop it counting a failure in the added iterations. I'll work out another way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution - collecting the fail count and then doing another loop after the first one finished has fixed it

```
        if(fails > 0)
            for(var f:int = i; f < fails + i; f++){
                var box:Shape = highlightChar(textField, f);
                if(box) boxes.addChild(box)
            }
```